# Best practice transferring list data from controller to the another controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display view once the list of content is retrieved from the database display it in the view.

On a high level what I am doing now works more or less but upon first access the previous results appears to be cached or still saved in my storage service.

This is what the service looks like.

```
function StorageService() {

    var opportunities;

    var getOpportunities = function() {
        return opportunities;
    }
    var setOpportunities = function(data) {
        opportunities = data;
    }
    return {
        getOpportunities: getOpportunities,
        setOpportunities: setOpportunities
    }
}
```

So when I click on the tab to getOpportunities I go direct to the view first and the load the data.

```
$scope.getAllOpportunities = function() {
$state.go("app.opportunities");
communicationService.getOpportunitiesAll().then(function(data) {
    StorageService.setOpportunities(data);
    if (!data.length) {
        $("#noShow").html("There are no opportunities");
    }
}, function(error) {})
```

}

once the view is rendered I retrieve the results and bind it to the view.

```
controller('OpportunitiesController', function($scope) {

$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterEnter", function(scopes, states) {
    $scope.opportunities = StorageService.getOpportunities();
});
```

What I am doing here also feels a bit wrong.

Is there a better way or a way that I can improve on the existing.

I want to load the view and the replace the loader with the data once the data is ready.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resolve the promise in the route, using the resolve property. That way, the data will always be available when the controller is instantiated.

https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/

Unless the resource is huge and you want to show som loading animation while getting the data. Then it would probably be more proper to just get the data in the controller.

```
controller('OpportunitiesController', function($scope) {

    communicationService.getOpportunitiesAll().then(function(response){
        $scope.opportunities = response;
    })

});
```

html:

```
<span ng-if="!opportunities">Getting stuff</span>
<span ng-if="opportunities">Stuff fetched</span>
```

Also, there is no use to have getter and setters in the service. Javascript objects are passed by reference so you can just expose the property directly.

Comment: The data is quite allot and preferably I want to load the view(with a loader) and then the data. Is there a way to do this with resolve. My experience is that the view won't load before the promise is resolved.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean. But can't you just load the view, then at controller instantiation you get the data (in the controller). Show the placeholder until that promise resolves? I will update my answer to show what i mean.